# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on ec2 machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, java

I have a java app on a large instance that will spawn up to 800 threads. I can run the application fine as user "root" but not as another user which I created. I get the deadly.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:657)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:943)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1325)
```

nightmare. I have tried increasing the stack size already in limits.conf to no avail. Please, help me out. What is different here for the root and other user?

Comment: Take a look at the output of `ulimit -a` for each user and see if there are any notable differences.

Comment: They are exactly the same. and thats what bugs me

Comment: Have you tried `java -Xmx1024m yourapp` ?

Comment: I'd recommend using `strace` to identify the underlying native call that's throwing an error so you can know exactly what you're looking at.

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you tell us more about your hardware/OS

Comment: have you heard of thread worker pools at all? many native threads are bad for a servers health!!!

Comment: Let me try strace. Thanks for pointing it out. I am running RHEL6-64bit large ec2 instance. @user37899 yes. I know thread pools. This is a stress test and hence the legit reason for 800 threads.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, setting the max number of processes higher seems to solve it, although I am sure there is only one process running with a lot of threads. Posting my final configs.

```
$ ulimit -u 81920

$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 59377
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 100000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 81920
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Linux threads do consume process IDs, so this behaviour is quite normal.